# How to tag a post and sort out the post by date?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I'm a newer in flask and I've already published a post from admin. Now I want to let the user to tag a post and they can store the tagged post. Could anyone please help me to achieve this function? Here's my models.py

```
class Post(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
  title = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
  content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
  description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
  image_file = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
  author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

  def __repr__(self):
    return f"Post('{self.date}', '{self.title}', '{self.content}')"
```

and my routes.py

```
@app.route("/post/<int:post_id>")
def post(post_id):
  post = Post.query.get_or_404(post_id)
  comments = Comment.query.filter(Comment.post_id==post.id)
  form = CommentForm()
  return render_template('post.html',post=post,comments=comments,form=form)


@app.route('/post/<int:post_id>/comment',methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def post_comment(post_id):
  post=Post.query.get_or_404(post_id)
  form=CommentForm()
  if form.validate_on_submit():
    db.session.add(Comment(content=form.comment.data,post_id=post.id,author_id=current_user.id))
    db.session.commit()
    flash("Your comment has been added to the post","success")
    return redirect(f'/post/{post.id}')
  comments=Comment.query.filter(Comment.post_id==post.id)
  return render_template('post.html',post=post,comments=comments,form=form)
```

and I also wondering what should I add in forms? I will be really thankful for all answers.

Answer (score 0):

Since a user can tag many posts and a post can be tagged by many users, I suggest you to use a (bidirectional) many to many relationship. Add two more columns to your Post model

```
class Post(db.Model):
    tagged_users_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"))
    tagged_users = db.relationship("User", backref="tagged_posts", foreign_keys=[tagged_users_id], uselist=True)
```

The backref attribute creates in the User model a column named "tagged_posts", which contains the id of all tagged posts as a list.

To tag a post or untag a post

```
post = Post()
user = User()
post.tagged_users.append(user)
post.tagged_users.remove(user)
```

To access tagged posts

```
user.tagged_posts
[tagged_post_id_1, tagged_post_id_2...]
post.tagged_users
[tagged_user_id_1, tagged_user_id_2...]
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but when I add the first two columns, it says" Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship User.post - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables. Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table." so how can I edit it ? And could you please tell me where I should add the "access tagged posts" and the specific operation in post.html?  Many thanks!

Comment: Although not 100% sure, I think this is because you have a foreign key for author_id without a author relationship.

Comment: Try adding author = db.relationship("User", foreign_keys=author_id, backref="written_posts") to the Post model